# Set SelectionActive in TreeViewItem WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

How to make TreeViewItem active? I can make it only selected using this code:

```
treeViewItem.IsSelected = true;
```

I tried do this:

```
treeViewItem.Focus()
```

But it's not working

How to make this treeViewItem active and selected?

Here is code of my treeView:

```
foreach(MyData dt in rootdata)
{
   TreeViewItem root = new TreeViewItem()
   root.IsExpanded = true;
   root.Header = dt .DataHeader;
   treeView.Items.Add(root);

   foreach(AnotherData dat in parentData)
   {
       TreeViewItem parent = new TreeViewItem()
       parent .IsExpanded = true;
       parent .Header = dat .DataHeader;
       root.Items.Add(parent);    

       foreach(AnotherData dat in childData)
       {
          TreeViewItem Child = new TreeViewItem()
          Child.IsExpanded = true;
          Child.Header = dat.DataHeader;


          if(this treeViewItem should be selected) 
          {
              child.IsSelected = true;
              child.Focus();
          }
           parent.Items.Add(Child);  
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you're getting call to "treeViewItem.IsSelected" ?

Comment: Yes, I've set trigger for IsSelectionActive in Xaml, I can see if this item selected or active.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. How do you obtain your TreeViewItem object, how does the tree look like (hierarchy) and how is the Tree populated?
Is it databindings, and are your treeViewItem visible (not inside a collapsed item)?

This is code I used to select, and expand, a given XML node.

```
private void SetSelected(XmlNode node)
{
    Stack<XmlNode> path = new Stack<XmlNode>();

    XmlDataProvider dp = FindResource("xml") as XmlDataProvider;
    XmlNode root = dp.Document.LastChild;

    XmlNode n1 = node;

    //path.Push(node);
    while (n1.ParentNode != root)
    {
        n1 = n1.ParentNode;
        if (n1 == null)
            return;
        path.Push(n1);
    }
    path.Push(root);

    ItemsControl control = tree;
    foreach (XmlNode n in path)
    {

        TreeViewItem tviItem = control.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(n) as TreeViewItem;
        tviItem.IsExpanded = true;
        tviItem.UpdateLayout();
        control = tviItem;
    }

    TreeViewItem resultItem = control.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(node) as TreeViewItem;
    resultItem.IsSelected = true;
    resultItem.Focus();
}
```

XAML:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="xml"/> 
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xml}}" x:Name=tree/>
```

What this code does is first to find the path down to the root, from the selected node.
(If you have the TreeViewItem instead of a XmlNode, or any other object, this also works, except you use item.Parent instead of n1.ParentNode)

Then it goes from the root, expands all nodes and updates the layout (important).

Finally, the selected node is set as IsSelected = true and given focus.

Comment: My treeView is expanded and I create my TreeViewItem like this:
TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();

Comment: How do you populate the tree?